# Custom Bootbox JS Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootbox JS to create modals and here is a sample of my current modal:

```
bootbox.dialog({
    message: '<center><img src="images/ajax.gif"></center><span id="progressUpdates"></span>',
    title: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Gathering Account Details',
    closeButton: false,
    className: "AccountProgress",   
    buttons: {
        progress: {
            label: "Continue",
            className: "btn-primary",
            callback: function() {
            }
        }
    }
 });
```

As you can see I am using "Close Button: false" which removes the X / escape method of closing the modal. I am using this as a progress indicator which will show steps as they have completed.

My goal is to not have any buttons there at all (remove buttons:) by default but then be able to add one when it has completed.

So have a modal with no buttons and then dyncamically add a button or enable a disabled button would work.

Is this possible?

Comment: are there multiple bootboxes ?

Answer (score 0):

after read the API docs on: http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html

Look at bootbox.dialog Section:
'A completely customisable dialog method which takes a single argument; an options object. The following snippet attempts to demonstrate these options as best as possible...:'

Here is a snippet:

```
buttons : {
   "Danger!" : {
      className: "btn-danger",
      callback: function() {}
    },
}
```

So, on your callback you can make it rains.. ;)
How? Start one thread on fiddle so I can help you.